# Create bouncing tick animation for order confirmation page - Adobe XD

Tags: creative-cloud, adobe-xd

New to XD and trying to make an animation where the tick transitions to a larger scale but then bounces back to its original size. So far I have already set up the animation for the trees moving in the background between two artboards so am unsure of how to target the arrow. I have tried to set it up with auto animate with easing set to bounce. The tick on the other artboard is named the same but slightly larger in size to create the bounce effect? I don't think I've set it up right though. I also don't fully understand at this stage the distinction between the auto-animate and the transition type in the interaction window on the right.

[image]